# C++ Error - warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a sorting program of numbers, but am getting the following error:

[image: ERRORS]

I was able to compile and work the code on an online c++ compiler, but when I must run it via the terminal so after attempting to do so, it won't compile anymore. There's actually nothing wrong with the code itself, since they're just warnings. But I would like to know how to fix them all, please!

The errors come from these parts of my code:

```
void sort()
{

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < storage.size()-1; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < storage.size()-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (storage[j] > storage[j+1]) // swap the values
            {
                int temp = storage[j];
                storage[j] = storage[j+1];
                storage[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print()
{
    
    for(int i = 0; i < storage.size(); i++)
        cout<<storage[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    vector<int> getList()
    {
        return storage;
    }
    
    void setList(vector<int> list)
    {
        storage = list;
    }
};

   void quickSort(int start, int end)

   {

   if (start < end)
   {
       int part = partition(start, end);
       quickSort(start, part - 1);
       quickSort(start + 1, end);
   }
   }

   void sort()
   {
       quickSort(0, storage.size() - 1);
   }

   void print()
   {
for(int i = 0; i < storage.size(); i++)
cout<<storage[i]<<" ";
cout<<endl;
   }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Declare `i` to be `unsigned int` instead of `int`.

Comment: 1) Please include errors/warnings as text, not pictures.  Not everybody on here can view pictures.
2) Have you studied `unsigned int` and related types?

Comment: `for (unsigned int i = 0; ...)`

Comment: @Barmar, thank you so much, it worked :D!

Comment: *"There's actually nothing wrong with the code itself, since they're just warnings."* -- no, there *is* something wrong with the code itself, since there are warnings. All "just warnings" should mean to you is that an executable can be created, the executable *might* give the results you want in most cases, and there is likely a test case that does *not* give the results you want (i.e. there is likely a bug in your code). Addressing all warnings, as you seem to be inclined to do, is a Good Idea. So good for you!

Comment: The better option is to use `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`. Even better to use the `size_type` of the container used: `decltype(storage.size())`.

Comment: With changing the type of `i` to be `unsigned` (or any unsigned type, like `size_t`), you'll get an unpleasant surprise (a long running outer loop, and an inner loop with undefined behaviour) if `storage.size()` is zero.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: But kudos, for reading the warnings and fixing them. You are on the right path. Do not accept code until it compiles without warning (with full warnings enabled). So good job.

Answer (score 0):

> would like to know how to fix them all, please!

The diagnostic says that you are comparing numbers of different signedness. You can fix that by not comparing numbers of different signedness. You can go with using signed type on both sides or unsigned type on both sides.

Aside from the warning, `storage.size()-1` is a dangerous operation unless you first enforce that the container is non-empty. If you subtract from a unsigned zero, you get a very large unsigned value. That is not bad by itself, but when you eventually use that large value as subscript, you get undefined behaviour. Simple solution to this is to add +1 to both sides of the comparison: `i+1 < storage.size()`.